# Summing up conditionally - two queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the balance of all my accounts. An account can be related to many transactions. A transaction is linked to two accounts. One account is the account that will be debited `transaction.debitaccountid`. And the other account will be credited `transaction.creditaccountid`.

A transaction can be made of 1:many TransactionLines. This allows a transaction to be split amoungst different categories or budgets.

So my structure:

[image]

(I have full control of the structure, so that can be changed)

I am trying to get a list of all accounts, with their balances. I will be doing this in linq later (ef core). But for now, just trying to find the most efficient way.

I'm stuck on a union with two queries, which I think, isn't great.

```
;WITH cte AS (
Select a.ExternalId AS ExternalId, a.Name, SUM(tl.Amount) AS Amount, 1 AS Credit
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON t.CreditAccountId = a.Id 
INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl
ON tl.TransactionId = t.id
WHERE a.AccountTypeId = 1
GROUP BY a.Id, a.ExternalId, a.Name

UNION

Select a.ExternalId AS ExternalId, a.Name, SUM(tl.Amount) AS Amount, -1 AS Credit
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON t.DebitAccountId = a.Id 
INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl
ON tl.TransactionId = t.id
WHERE a.AccountTypeId = 1
GROUP BY a.Id, a.ExternalId, a.Name
)
SELECT ExternalId, Name, SUM(Amount * Credit) FROM cte
GROUP BY ExternalId, Name
```

I get the right answer, but it seems inefficient. Also, I'll need to do this in link, so will be two queries from my application, and then the results handled in linq.

Is there a way to do this in a single SQL query? Maybe join on the transaction with an OR? But then, not sure how to work out if it's a debit or credit value.

Maybe I need to store the amount in the transaction table? But that could go wrong. Might be easier and can be made safe?

edit:
This nearly works. But i cant group correctly:

```
Select a.ExternalId AS ExternalId, a.Name, 
SUM(tl.Amount) *  
case when t.CreditAccountId = a.Id then 1 
when t.DebitAccountId = a.Id then -1 end
as Amt 
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON (t.CreditAccountId = a.Id OR t.DebitAccountId = a.Id )
INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl
ON tl.TransactionId = t.id
WHERE a.AccountTypeId = 1
GROUP BY a.Id, a.ExternalId, a.Name, t.CreditAccountId, t.DebitAccountId
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Those need to be grouped by ExternalId and Name, with the Amount summed.

Edit 2:
Fixed it.

```
Select a.ExternalId AS ExternalId, a.Name, 
SUM(tl.Amount *  
case when t.CreditAccountId = a.Id then 1 
when t.DebitAccountId = a.Id then -1 end)
as Amt 
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON (t.CreditAccountId = a.Id OR t.DebitAccountId = a.Id )
INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl
ON tl.TransactionId = t.id
WHERE a.AccountTypeId = 1
GROUP BY a.Id, a.ExternalId, a.Name--, t.CreditAccountId, t.DebitAccountId
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

I think you can use `OR` and `CASE` statements to achieve the results in the same query. Please check below query if it can help.

```
Select a.ExternalId AS ExternalId, a.Name, 
SUM(tl.Amount *  
case when t.CreditAccountId = a.Id then 1 
when t.DebitAccountId = a.Id then -1 end)
as Amt 
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON (t.CreditAccountId = a.Id OR t.DebitAccountId = a.Id )
INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl
ON tl.TransactionId = t.id
WHERE a.AccountTypeId = 1
GROUP BY a.Id, a.ExternalId, a.Name
```

Comment: Thanks. That nearly works, but the introduction of the CreditAccountID and DebitAccountId fields, make the grouping tricky. I've added your idea and the results to the question.

Comment: @Craig In the question, it is mentioned that the final output will be the final balance of the accounts and group with `t.CreditAccountId, t.DebitAccountId` will not help you it will give you the final according to these grouping id's. Please suggest if I am missing some point.

Comment: Bringing in those fields into the query, forces me to add them to the groupby. And that created nearly the right result. But the expected result would be just two rows. If you look at the new result set (I may have misunderstood your answer, as the extra SUM was causing invalid values), you can see that the Amount is now right... I just need to sum those up, somehow. And I should have 'Another Bank: 500', and 'My Bank account: 4444.80'. So, with your fix, I just need to sum up that result. You had an extra SUM - but it was giving crazy answers. Maybe that's the fix. If I can get it right.

Comment: I fixed it! Posting result.

Comment: In the query, you have edited in the question you missed the `sum` of the `case` statement. If you are using `sum` as mentioned in the answer there is no need to `group bu id's`

Comment: Great, if you have fixed :)

Comment: Yes, thanks. If it's OK, I'll suggest an edit o your answer, as there was a syntax issue.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for your edit, and accepting the answer. As the final motive is to help and learn from each other which should be fulfilled. :)